# Couldn't a house elf have transported Harry to the safe place?

Tags: harry-potter

Instead of falling into the *Battle of Seven Potters*, why didn't the Order order a house elf to transport Harry to the safe place?

Comment: Wouldn't this still be negated by "the trace"?? Wasn't this the reason for the *Seven Potters* episode in the first place?

Comment: At the time of the *Battle of the Seven Potters*, Harry still had *The Trace* on him; he still hadn't reached his birthday yet (is that 17 or 18?? Don't remember.). It was the reason they didn't allow him to Apparate or use other magical means of transport; they had to physically move him so he could not be traced through *The Trace*. Any magic used could allow him to be traced, that, I'd assume also includes by house elf.

Comment: Not the same as magical transport. That is magical conveyance, not transport. You are choosing to nit pick at my statement and not see it for what it's worth.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Two reasons spring to mind:

1. **House-elf magic is susceptible to the Trace.**

   Witness Dobby’s use of a Hover charm in *Chamber of Secrets* getting Harry in trouble, despite it not being Harry who cast the charm. If we assume the Ministry could similarly detect a House Elf apparating in or out of Privet Drive, then Harry’s still stuck:

   > [Pius Thicknesse]’s made it an imprisonable offense to connect this house to the Floo Network, place a Portkey here, or Apparate in or out.
   >
   > — *Deathly Hallows*, chapter 4 (*The Seven Potters*)

   We don’t know whether the Ministry would be able to detect where Harry went immediately, but it puts him on shaky legal ground at best. When Rufus Scrimgeour came to give the trio the contents of Dumbledore’s will, he’d also have to bring an Auror with which to arrest Harry.
2. **They didn’t think of it.**

   Throughout the books, we see wizards disregard the ability of House-Elves (for example, their ability to apparate in and out of places that humans can’t). It’s quite possible none of them thought to ask a House-Elf to do it for them, instead trusting in their own (perceived) superior skills in defensive magic.

Comment: Just an aside, but why didn't Harry get in trouble for Dobby apparating in and out during the cake incident? I'm sure Dobby didn't walk...

Comment: @Moo Hmm, good point. Perhaps (1) doesn’t stand then, and House-Elf apparition isn’t Trace-susceptible (which relates to (2), with the Ministry underestimating House-Elves). Alternatively, the fact that Harry *couldn’t* have performed those Apparitions may have got him off the hook (although why they didn’t surmise the same person performed the hover charm is another mystery).

Answer (score 5):

A house elf was **not** part of Dumbledore's plan, Dumbledore wanted Voldemort to believe that Snape is well informed and loyal.

So that Snape will be in a unique position of power so that Voldemort will reward Snape as new Headmaster of Hogwarts (to protect the students of course).

> from Deathly Hallows chapter the Prince's tale
>
> “**You will have to give Voldemort the correct date of Harry’s departure** from his aunt and uncle’s,” said Dumbledore. “Not to do so will raise suspicion, when Voldemort believes you so well informed. However, **you must plant the idea of decoys; that, I think, ought to ensure Harry’s safety.** Try Confunding Mundungus Fletcher. And Severus, if you are forced to take part in the chase, be sure to act your part convincingly. . . . I am counting upon you to **remain in Lord Voldemort’s good books as long as possible, or Hogwarts will be left to the mercy of the Carrows. . . .”**

Dumbledore **wanted Voldemort to know** the correct date of Harry's departure. Dumbledore **wanted the Seven Potters incident to happen** (to protect the students of Hogwarts of course).

By the way seven Potters and Voldemort's intended Seven horcruxes. Nice coincidence. Seven is a powerful number in magic.